# About a representation of matrix algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

> Let $\rho: M_n(\mathbb R)\rightarrow M_{2n}(\mathbb R)$ be an algebra morphism, i.e., a $2n$-dimensional real representation of the matrix algebra $M_n(\mathbb R)$. Then what can we say about the map $\rho$?

I know there is a theorem which asserts that the matrix algebra is simple, and there is essentially only one irreducible representation of the matrix algebra. There is a book in which it suggests such a representation must be "two copies" of the irreducible representation, but I cannot figure out this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The matrix algebra is simple, so in particular semisimple. Hence every indecomposable representation of it is equivalent to a direct summand of the regular representation.

Comment: Thank you very much! I know little about representation theory, I know your assertion but hadn't understood "direct sum" correctly, and now I think I have understood it.